# Why this predicate is written in this way?

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I am having a hard time to understand why the second predicate of findall is written as this instead of **collect_found([],L)** directly.

```
:- dynamic found/1.
findall(X, G, _) :-
   asserta(found(mark)),
   call(G),
   asserta(found(result(X))),
   fail.
findall(_, _, L) :- collect_found([], M), !, L = M.

collect_found(S, L) :-
   getnext(X),
   !,
   collect_found([X|S], L).
collect_found(L, L).

getnext(Y) :- retract(found(X)), !, X = result(Y).
```

Is there any advantage by writing in this way?

Comment: It guards against L being instantiated to a value which might interfere, causing e.g. unintended backtracking. Kinda similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363474/prolog-why-is-this-a-bad-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This code is from the 5th edition of Programming in Prolog by Clocksin & Mellish. Since it collides with the built-in `findall/3`, I will use the name `cmfindall/3` for their definition)

First, to answer your question: There is in fact no difference between the code in the book and your suggestion. Thus:

```
cmfindall(_, _, L) :- collect_found([], M), !, L = M.
```

and

```
cmfindall(_, _, L) :- collect_found([], L).
```

are (in this very context) the same. To see this, let's look at the definition of `collect_found/2`. What is the role of the second argument in it? To better highlight it, I will remove everything that is not related to the second argument:

```
collect_found(_, L) :-
   ...,
   !,
   collect_found(_, L).
collect_found(L, L).
```

From this we see that the second argument has only an influence at the end when it is unified with the first argument. And thus, there is no need to delay that unification after the goal.

Why was the code written like that? It seems the authors wanted to ensure that the removal of `found/1` facts will always be performed, and (maybe in a previous, pre 1981 version) the second argument was sensitive to being instantiated.

Also note that the authors remark (p.168,2nd par):

> Any occurrence of `findall` used within the second argument of another `findall` will be treated correctly.

Now they clearly did not consider:

```
?- catch(cmfindall(Y,(Y=2;throw(ex)),_),ex,false).
   false.
?- cmfindall(X,(X=1;catch(cmfindall(Y,(Y=2;throw(ex)),_),ex,false)),Xs).
   Xs = [2], unexpected.
   Xs = [1]. % expected, but not found
```

Handling such cases correctly is a pretty dirty job since there is still no agreement between systems which primitives to use to handle them cleanly.

Comment: I really appreaciate your insight of the issue! I am a beginner at this language. I just didn't get why the choice of being written as the original version would have something to do with the found/1 predicate, given that it is a predicate that is within the zone you described as ,so to say, "not affected" by what the second argument is.

Comment: @exci: As a beginner, stick to the pure monotonic part of Prolog, first. There you can learn a lot that you will need for full Prolog anyway, but it keeps you focused. I'd suggest you start with [tag:successor-arithmetics].